# How to run camel route only once

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have just begun to work with Apache-Camel. I am looking for a component to cause the route, execute only once. Right now I use 'File' component for running the route. I think it might not be the proper way since the route does not need any files. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to stop route, or suspend route after poll, or after first Exchange? Or keep route in registry and invoke only once? It is unclear, what exactly you want. Maybe you could add your actual solution, to make it clear.

Comment: I want the route to be run and stop.

Comment: You can check when the exchange has completed and then send a signal to stop the route.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Camel!  Have you considered using a Timer, with 'repeatCount' specified?